# jsp errorpage--exception?

Tags: jsp

```
 <%@ page isErrorPage = "true"%>
    <body>
    <h2>Your application has generated an error</h2>
    <h3>Please check for the error given below</h3>
    <b>Exception:</b><br> 
    <font color="red"><%= exception.toString() %></font>
    </body>
```

I want to know in the JSP Expression what does exception.toString() - exception object is used for ??

Can we alternatively make a use of <%= exception.getMessage() %>??

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking whats contained in the exception variable.

`exception` is a [JSP implicit](http://www.jsptutorial.net/jsp-implicit-objects-tutorial.aspx) variable

The `exception` variable contains any Exception thrown on the previous JSP page with an `errorPage` directive that forwards to a page with an `isErrorPage` directive.

e.g.

If you had a JSP  (index.jsp) which throws an exception (I have deliberately thrown a NumberFormatException by parsing a String, obviously you wouldn't write a page that does this, its just an example)

```
<%@ page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<% Integer.parseInt("foo"); //throws an exception %>
```

This will forward to error.jsp,

If error.jsp was

```
<%@ page isErrorPage = "true"%>
<body>
<h2>Your application has generated an error</h2>
<h3>Please check for the error given below</h3>
<b>Exception:</b><br> 
<font color="red"><%= exception.toString() %></font>
</body>
```

Because it has the

```
<%@ page isErrorPage = "true"%>
```

page directive, the implicit variable `exception` will contain the Exception thrown in the previous jsp

So when you request index.jsp, the Exception will be thrown, and forwarded to error.jsp which will output html like this

```
<body>
<h2>Your application has generated an error</h2>
<h3>Please check for the error given below</h3>
<b>Exception:</b><br> 
<font color="red">java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo"</font>
</body>
```

As @JB Nizet mentions exception is an instanceof Throwable calling `exception.getMessage()` `For input string: "foo"` instead of `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo"`

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` and `getMessage()` are two methods of [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), and you may of course call both. They don't do the same thing, though. To know what they do, read their documentation.